# Windows 7 Control Panel - Programs and Features

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

When I try to uninstall any program, the message box I receive contains the following:

Programs and Features:

Please wait until the current program is finished uninstalling or being changed.

There are no programs at that time being changed or uninstalled.  Please advise how to get rid of this problem preventing me from taking removal actions.

Thank you.

Comment: Try rebooting..

Comment: Just be patient, sometimes uninstalls are working the background. You probably uninstalled a program just before you tried uninstalling a second the time you got this message. Windows will only allow one uninstall at a time; hence the warning.

Answer (score -1):

Rebooting worked.  Lost all my notepad work, but what the heck.  Problem solved.

Comment: Obvious advice. Save all work in progress **before rebooting**.